# Add custom text to WP Title

Tags: php, wordpress, meta-tags, facebook-opengraph, feed

I am able to add a custom text to my title of a specified post id but it does not apply to my meta title and my rss feed title. It is seen only by the user on the current page.

I tried using is_feed() but with no success...

This is what I'v done so far:

```
add_filter('the_title', 'add_my_title', 10, 2); 
function add_my_title($title) { 
$my_custom_text = 'Sponsored: '; 
if(is_single( '99' )) { $title = $my_custom_text.$title; } 
return $title; }
```

My title should look like:

> "Sponsored: Are you prepared for the Black Friday?"

**and must be the same/applied everywhere - html, feed, facebook/twitter opengraph etc.**

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to add text to the headers from the settings of your seo-plugin.